# LINQ to SQL With the where with case statement

Tags: .net, sql, linq, case, where-clause

I have a SQL query that I want to convert into LINQ. I have pulled the data in to datatable.I am quite confused how to write the WHERE part of the query. The condition is dependent on a column in the table, If col_Con is "G" then use greater than on col_Val and 30(any value) else if col_Con is "L" then use less than condition on col_Val and 30(any value)

I am using Sqlserver 2005 for the SQL query part .

```
SELECT *
FROM   Mytable
WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN col_Con= 'G' THEN 
        col_Val
    ELSE 
        30
    END 
        <= 
    CASE
    WHEN col_Con= = 'L' THEN 
        30
    ELSE 
        col_Val
    END
```

Here is the start of my Linq

```
            //Mytable is a DataTable
            var drs = from DataRow dr in Mytable.Rows
            where   
            ...
            select dr;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var drs = from DataRow dr in Mytable.Rows
            where   
            (col_Con == 'G' ? col_Val : 30) <= (col_Con == 'L' ? 30 : col_Val)
            select dr;
```

Comment: The ternary operator (?:) is the correct way to generate a `CASE` in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: It's not really a CASE but an if. Although the SQL translation will be a CASE. You can see the full SQL statement in LinqPad to check that out.

Comment: I think 'L' needs to be changed to 'G' other wise both sides will be same. or one of 30 : col_Val swapped !

Comment: I just translated your SQL statement to LINQ. The LINQ query is exactly the same as the SQL.