# SQL to Linq Where Case Statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I write the following SQL in Linq:

```
SELECT clientID, businessName 
  FROM clients 
  WHERE (regionID = CASE WHEN '{0}' = -1 THEN regionID ELSE '{0}' END)
  ORDER BY businessName
```

This is what I have so far, but I not sure how to translate the where case statement:

```
var result = context.clients
    .OrderBy(x => x.businessName)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            x.clientID, x.businessName, x.active, x.regionID
        })
    .OrderBy(x=> x.businessName);
```

Comment: Can you explain the `CASE` part a bit?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also, that's not a valid SQL query. It looks like a format string that someone calls String.Format on.

Comment: Have a look at [LINQ to SQL With the where with case statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705914/linq-to-sql-with-the-where-with-case-statement)

Comment: '{0}' is where there is a variable in string format.  The SQL will either select all records if the variable is -1 else select records = to the variable passed.

Comment: Edit: The case on the Where is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ternary statements in the query. I'm not sure if it translates to a case statement in SQL, but you can use LINQPad to find out.

Assuming 'val' contains the value that would be inserted for {0}...

```
var result = context.clients
    .OrderBy(x => x.businessName)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            x.clientID, 
            x.businessName, 
            x.active, 
            x.regionID == -1 ? val : x.regionID
        })
    .OrderBy(x=> x.businessName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is called parameter, you can can add a section like

```
 .Where(a=>a.RegionID == ((parameter == -1) ? a.RegionID : parameter));
```

There is another method where you can avoid the case statement by building your query like

```
var query = context.clients.AsQueryable();

if (parameter != -1)
    query = query.Where(a=>a.regionID == parameter);


var result = query
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name )
    .Select(x => new
    {
       x.clientID, x.businessName
    });
```

If parameter is -1, this will generate something like

```
SELECT clientID, businessName 
FROM clients 
ORDER BY businessName
```

otherwise it will generate something like

```
SELECT clientID, businessName 
FROM clients 
WHERE (regionID = parameter)
ORDER BY businessName
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.  I was working towards the 2nd method you posted, will try it out later.